# ()=>getItem("123") is Func(bool) or Func(string,bool)

Tags: c#, .net

For lambda expresssion `()=>getItem("123")`, is it Func(bool) or Func(string,bool), suppose getItem return bool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a `Func<bool>`.

The clue is in the `() =>` part: This means that the function has no input parameters.

Comment: Some crazy people might call it `unit`... well the `()` part at least.

Comment: @LukeH what's the expression which corresponding to Func<string,bool>

Comment: @user: The method `getItem()` satisfies that delegate.  Otherwise, this lambda would too: `s => getItem(s)`.

Comment: but I want to give the parameter like getItem("123"), how to express it to Func<string,bool>

Comment: @user - Try doing this `requiresLambda(getItem);`

Comment: @user: If you want it to be a `Func<string,bool>` calling `getItem("123")`, you'd have to explicitly give the argument a type if it is not used.  This would also satisfy the delegate: `(String s) => getItem("123")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refactor this to a `Func<string,bool>` then pull the literal "123" out and treat it as an input parameter instead:

```
bool getItem(string input) { ... }

Func<bool> selector = () => getItem("123");
Func<string,bool> selector2= str => getItem(str);     

bool result1 = selector();
bool result2 = selector2("123");

Assert.AreEqual(result1,result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the answer is **neither**. [Lambda expressions are typeless](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/01/11/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-two/)